# Пропуск присваивания значения uniform переменной

Tags: glsl, opengles, opengl

Какое значение будет в **fragment-шейдере** иметь **sampler2D uniform-переменная**, если я **не** присвою ей значения в коде?
Такой же вопрос об остальных **uniform-переменных**. Например, если у меня есть в **fragment-шейдере** переменная типа **vec4**, то она будет содержать ***null*** значение, если я **не** инициализирую ее в коде? Или **OpenGL** как-то пропускает куски в шейдере, которые работают с **не** инициализированными переменными? Прошу дать справку.

Использую **OpenGL ES 2.0**. **GLSL** - кажется, версия **1.0**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем, vec4 у меня по умолчанию заполняется нулями. Думаю все uniform-переменные, которые не имеют значения, заполняются нулями. С sampler2D та же история - texture2D() возвращает vec4 с нулями.